# Expand number of rows by column count VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I'm definitely a beginner when it comes to VBA beyond editing other peoples Macros. I have a project I'm working on where I need to combine data taken from the first pivot row and column headers and paste it in a new worksheet.

I need to take the row values in column A (which can be variable in data and count) multiply each row by the number of columns (also can be variable in data and count) such that if I have 3 columns (A,B,C) and two rows(1,2) before the macro after I will have 6 rows and 3 columns with the first 3 rows all having the same data as the original row 1 and the second 3 rows with the same data as the original row 2.

Then I have to paste down the columns to match the rows as well as the data to match the row and columns.

Original Pivot:

[image]

Goal After Macro:

[image]

I know I need to count the number of columns declare that a variable and then use that variable to copy the rows over to the new worksheet using a loop. I don't believe using a second pivot will work as it wont use the column header a cell value even if I do a tabular view. I've tried writing some code but I cant get to it as I'm on my home computer.

Any advise on how to get past the first part of having it count the number of columns and expand the rows would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've provided an answer to accomplish what you want, but I honestly think your original table is in a better Normalized format.  Why do you want to break it down into the form of Sheet2, out of curiosity?

Comment: Thanks PJ I'll test it in just a bit on my end. Its because a later step in the project requires the accnt and value sections to be next to each other for upload into a firm system.

Comment: That explains it.  Excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  This should do what you are looking for.  You will just need to set the value of Sheet2("A1") manually to Accnt..

**TESTED:**

```
Private Sub FormShift()

Dim tRow As Long     'target Row
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
tRow = 2

For iRow = 2 To lastRow
    For iCol = 2 To lastCol
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCol)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, 3) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, iCol)
        tRow = tRow + 1
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what I needed and now I know how to do for loops in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub horz_vert()

noOfColumns = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
noOfRows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

For j = 1 To noOfRows
 For I = 1 To noOfColumns
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells((I + 1) + (j - 1) * noOfColumns, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j + 1, 1)
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells((I + 1) + (j - 1) * noOfColumns, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, I + 1)
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells((I + 1) + (j - 1) * noOfColumns, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j + 1, I + 1)
 Next
Next

End Sub
```